# Java program to read parenthesis, curly braces, and brackets

Tags: java

I'm supposed to create a Java program which reads expressions that contain, among other items, braces { }, 
brackets [ ], and parentheses ( ).  My program should be properly 
nested and that ‘(‘ matches ‘)’, ‘[‘ matches ‘]’, and ‘{’ matches ‘}‘ The 
program should be terminated by a ‘$’ at the beginning of an input line. 
These are supposed to be sample runs of my program:

```
Enter an Expression:
A[F + X {Y – 2}] 
The expression is Legal

Enter an Expression: 
B+[3 – {X/2})*19 + 2/(X – 7) 
ERROR—‘]’ expected 

Enter an Expression:
()) ( 
ERROR--‘)’ without ‘(‘ 
$
```

I created a class called BalancedExpression and a driver called ExpressionChecker.
I completed my BalancedExpression class. But, I'm having trouble setting up my driver to print out an expression using an InputStreamReader and a BufferedReader. The only thing I was able to figure out was how to terminate my program by letting the user enter a $.

Here is my code so far:

Balanced Expression class:

```
public class BalancedExpression
{
public BalancedExpression() // Default Constructor
{
  sp = 0; // the stack pointer
  theStack = new int[MAX_STACK_SIZE]; 
} 

public void push(int value) // Method to push an expression into the stack
{ 
  if (!full()) 
    theStack[sp++] = value; 
} 

public int pop() // Method to pop an expression out of the stack
{ 
  if (!empty()) 
    return theStack[--sp]; 

  else 
    return -1;  
} 

public boolean full() // Method to determine if the stack is full
{ 
  if (sp == MAX_STACK_SIZE) 
    return true; 

  else 
    return false; 
} 

public boolean empty() // Method to determine if the stack is empty
{ 
  if (sp == 0) 
    return true; 

  else 
    return false; 
} 

public static boolean checkExpression(String ex) // Method to check Expression in stack
{
    BalancedExpression stExpression = new BalancedExpression();
    for(int i = 0; i<  MAX_STACK_SIZE; i++)
    {
        char ch = ex.charAt(i);
        if(ch == '(' || ch == '{' ||  ch == '[')
            stExpression.push(ch);
        else if(ch == ')' && !stExpression.empty() && stExpression.equals('('))
            stExpression.pop();
        else if(ch == '}' && !stExpression.empty() && stExpression.equals('{'))
            stExpression.pop();
        else if(ch == ']' && !stExpression.empty() && stExpression.equals('['))
            stExpression.pop();
        else if(ch == ')' || ch == '}' ||  ch == ']' )
            return false;
    }
    if(!stExpression.empty())
        return false;
    return true;
}

private int sp; 
private int[] theStack; 
private static final int MAX_STACK_SIZE = 6;

}// End of class BalancedExpression
```

My Driver Program:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ExpressionChecker
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in); 
    BufferedReader console = new BufferedReader(reader); 

    BalancedExpression exp = new BalancedExpression();
    String expression = "";

    do
    {
        try{
        System.out.print("Enter an Expression: ");
        expression = console.readLine();

        if("$".equals(expression)) 
            break;

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("IO error:" + e);
        }

    }while(!expression.equals(""));// End of while loop
}
}// End of class ExpressionChecker
```

Can anyone please help me develop my driver program to print out an output similar to the sample example?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So you need help with command line io?

Comment: Modify the checkExpression method to print out when the pair of brackets fails to match.

Comment: I'm having trouble setting up my driver to print **out** an expression using an **Input** StreamReader and a BufferedReader
I can't understand this part, you want to show the user some text?

Comment: I am sure if you got this far you will mange the rest - as far as I can tell you only have to check if the closing element matches the top most opening element. If thats not the case you can print out your warning message.

Comment: So basicly before you call pop you should check if you are popping the right element. Not that hard, I am sure you will manage.

Comment: you need to simply match the opened and closed brackets? why not simply count and compare them (if amount of '(' is larger then the amount of ')' something is wrong and vice verca). But if you like to show the place where the wrongly placed bracket is set you will require a smarter routine.

Answer (score 0):

In the *if statements*  in *checkExpression* method you are using

> `stExpression.equals()`

while what you want to do is to 'peek' at the value on the top of the stack.

Adding simple method that pops the value, pushes it back and returns it should solve the problem(at least this part).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very short example where you can do the above check very easily :) We have `Stack` class in Java, it will make the program very easy. Please find below the simple code for this question:

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class StackChar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enete an expression : ");
        String expr = sc.nextLine();

        if(checkvalidExpression(expr)){
            System.out.println("The Expression  '"+expr+"'  is a valid expression!!!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("The Expression  '"+expr+"'  is a NOT a valid expression!!!");
        }

    }

    public static boolean checkvalidExpression(String expr){

        Stack<Character> charStack = new Stack<Character>();

        int len = expr.length();
        char exprChar = ' ';

        for(int indexOfExpr = 0; indexOfExpr<len; indexOfExpr++){
            exprChar = expr.charAt(indexOfExpr);

            if(exprChar == '(' || exprChar == '{' ||  exprChar == '['){
                charStack.push(exprChar);
            }
            else if(exprChar == ')' && !charStack.empty()){
                if(charStack.peek() == '('){
                    charStack.pop();
                }
            }
            else if(exprChar == '}' && !charStack.empty()){
                if(charStack.peek() == '{'){
                    charStack.pop();
                }
            }
            else if(exprChar == ']' && !charStack.empty()){
                if(charStack.peek() == '['){
                    charStack.pop();
                }
            }

            else if(exprChar == ')' || exprChar == '}' ||  exprChar == ']' ){
                return false;
            }

        }
        if(!charStack.empty())
            return false;

        return true;

    }

}
```